# Regex for removing unneccessary text from inside a specific xml tag

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with XML statements as such:

```
<rdfs:label>(mild) (585.2)</rdfs:label>
```

How would I remove the text in between parantheses, not the numbers so the data would read:

```
<rdfs:label>(585.2)</rdfs:label>
```

The number in rdfs:label may be a whole number, a decimal of up to two places, or a range composed of whole numbers, decimals or a combination of both.

I've tried the following regex but it does not seem to be working correctly:

```
<rdfs:label>?([0-9]*)
\(\1
```

I just bit the bullet and wrote a java method to handle the irregular data.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the numbers in between the label tags, like get 600 from <rdfs:label>600</rdfs:label>?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want, although there are some values which have a V or an E in front of the number which need to be preserved. The final goal is to generate a text file which represents the tree structure of the data

Comment: Use an XML parser. Not regular expressions.

Comment: Notepad++ isn't a tool to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the java method that I used to solve this issue

```
String methodName(String a){
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
                if(a.charAt(i) == '('){
                    if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i+1)) || (a.charAt(i+1) == 'V' && Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i+2))) || (a.charAt(i+1) == 'E' && Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i+2)))){
                        for(int v = i; v < a.length(); v++){
                            if(a.charAt(v) == ')'){
                                return(a.substring(i+1,v));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first capturing group of this `regex` takes the first set of parentheses and whatever is between them, with the following space.

```
<.*>(\(.*\)\s)
```

Comment: using <.*>(\(.*\)\s) as find and replacing it with nothing alters 0 rows